# Certification Failed : Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i uploaded app to windows phone 8 marketplace, but i got result as failed,

```
Name: FBNC VIETNAM
Version: 1.0.0.0
Company Name: FBNC Việt Nam
Windows Phone OS Version: 7.1
Test ID: 717923
```

it's says :

```
The app directs the user to a web experience without the user input upon launch. The application directs the user to
m.youtube.com/user/FBNCVietnam.
```

i do not understand the real result.

what i did in my code is, i just redirect to some link on load :

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                webbrw.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/FBNCVietnam", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                                  webbrw.Navigated += webbrw_Navigated;
                    webbrw.NavigationFailed += webbrw_NavigationFailed;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not able to load Application");
```

}
        }

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft's acceptance policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two statements; Do you see the pattern?

> The app directs the user to a web experience without the user input upon launch.
>
> i just redirect to some link on load :

Microsoft are saying: don't redirect the user to a web site without asking.

Comment: thanks for reply, Oh. Is this something easy to fix?

Comment: Do you actually read the things you see? I quote:"**don't redirect the user to a web site without asking**".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be called fix, But the user will know that he'll go on youtube:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Go to youtube chanel in web?", "GotYou", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                  {
                    webbrw.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/FBNCVietnam", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                                  webbrw.Navigated += webbrw_Navigated;
                    webbrw.NavigationFailed += webbrw_NavigationFailed;
                  }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not able to load Application");
            }
```

**This is an example! I do not see all your UI and I do not know how best to notify.**

It bothers me that you are sending user to web by event
MainPage_Loaded is the main functionality of your application? If so,  may best not ask for consent for conversion, but only to inform.

```
MessageBox.Show("Now you will go to youtube channel");
```

Or notify other ways. The application should not scare the user. A referral to a web page without warning and pressing buttons can be intimidating. :)